# GoogleMap等と連携して距離を求める

Tags: html

お世話になります。

Webで有名なGoogleMap等と連携して、手持ちのリストの住所と目的地の住所の距離を
自動で算出してくれる仕組みを作りたいと考えています。そのために必要な環境、開発言語
などを教えていただきたいと思います。

一つ一つ住所を入れなおしてWebで検索すればいい話ですが、リストにある住所が
2,30あると、その都度入れなおすのは面倒なため、一発で出してくれる仕組みを求めています。

機能の手順を書きに記します。

1.データベース、あるいはExcelなどに、出発地点となる候補の名前と住所がある。
2.目的地の住所を入力する。
3.GoogleMapなどの地図検索機能を使用し、リストのすべての住所から目的地までの距離を
算出する。
4.もっとも距離が近いものを結果として表示(名称、住所、所要距離)する。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 仮にGoogleMapを使うとした場合、住所の緯度経度を使って2点間の距離を測るということをかんがえているのでしょうか。つまり、そういう距離の算出方法も含めて、教えてほしいということなのでしょうか。開発環境や言語は色々ありますので、自分の使える言語や慣れている環境なども併記してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ja)を使えば住所から緯度経度を求めることができます。

2点の緯度経度から距離を計算する方法はいろいろなwebサイトで紹介されていますので、「緯度経度 距離」などで検索してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
いろいろ調べてみます。
ご指摘ありがとうございました。